# How to check for array in java

Tags: java, groovy

I am getting values params[point.id] . i want to check whether params[point.id] is array or not ,how to do this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This way: `object.getClass().isArray()`

Answer (score 10):

Try [`isArray()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isArray%28%29),

```
foo.getClass().isArray();
```

where `foo` is the [`Object`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) in question.